# How to use $1, $n from awk in Makefile

Tags: awk, makefile

I have this to get the number of lines of my python files with relative path and correct padding for number of lines:

```
$ find ./ -name "*.py" -exec wc -l {} \;| awk '{printf "%10s %s\n", $1, $2}'
 29 ./setup.py
 28 ./proj_one/setup.py
896 ./proj_one/proj_one/data_ns.py
169 ./proj_one/proj_one/lib.py
310 ./proj_one/proj_one/base.py
  0 ./proj_one/proj_one/__init__.py
 72 ./proj_one/tests/lib_test.py
```

I would like to have it in a Makefile::

```
 $ cat Makefile
 pfile_wc:
            @find ./ -name "*.py" -exec wc -l {} \;| awk '{printf "%10s %s\n", $1, $2}'
```

So I could call it with:

```
$ make pfile_wc
```

I can't get to properly escape/use the `$1` and `$2` in the Makefile

Comment: can be done with awk alone... `find -name "*.txt" -exec awk 'END{printf "%10s %s\n", NR, FILENAME}' {} \;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prepend your $ symbol with another one:

```
@find ./ -name "*.py" -exec wc -l {} \;| awk '{printf "%10s %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```